# Jest - testing eventChannel Redux-saga

Tags: javascript, jestjs, redux-saga, redux-saga-test-plan

I have one sagas file with  2 functions, one is the saga itself, and the other is the function that is called by my saga, which uses the `eventChannel` from `redux-saga` library.

```
export const hardwareBackChannel = () => eventChannel((emit): {} => {
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwarePress', () => {
    emit(true);
    return true; 
  });
  return (): * => {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener();
  };
});

export function* handleBackButtonEvent() {
  yield put(hardwareBackChannel());
}
```

I was able to test my `handleBackButtonEvent` successfully with:

```
  describe('handleBackButtonEvent', () => {
    it('should call back button pressed action', () => {
      testSaga(handleBackButtonEvent)
        .next()
        .put(
          hardwareBackChannel(),
        );
    });
  });
```

But I wasn't able to figure out how I can test the `hardwareBackChannel` itself using `testSaga`. Is there a way to do that? If not, how can I potentially cover this part of the code on my tests?

I've trying to search all day but I found just threads with ways to test my saga, not my `hardwareBackChannel` function itself.

Thanks advance

Comment: Did you figure it out?